# can i remove characters starting from ( to ) in python

Tags: python, arrays, character

i need a help to remove some characters with python 
Code :

```py
txt = 'Congo (Congo-Brazzaville)'
```

can i remove characters starting from  (  to  )

so that txt after that is  like : 'Congo'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `re` package:

```py
>>> import re
>>> txt = re.sub("\(.*\)", "", txt)
>>> txt
'Congo '
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace function:

txt = txt.replace("string", "to be replace with")